# Create img in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image

How to create img tag in jQuery and set it as only content of some div?

If target div has some content, replace it and put dynamically created img tag.

Here is What I have tried:

```
        $(".someClass").click(function(){

             var $img = $('<img allowfullscreen  ></img>', {
                'width': 650,
                'height': 580,              
                'src': $(this).find('img').attr('data')
             });
             $('#someId').html($img);

        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a "we do code for you" site. We are more than happy to *help* you achieve your goal, provided you do some ground work first. Maybe you should try something first, show us what you've tried, and we can suggest improvements. jQuery has extensive documentation, which you can [read here](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: what do you mean by "create image"? Is the image located in web like www.a.com/a.jpg or do you want to "really" create an image (actually draw) on client side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $img=$("<img />",{"src":url});
$(target_id).html($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Image` object like this:

```
var img = new Image() 
img.src = 'image.jpg'
```