# Create iframe in jQuery again asking

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

How to create iframe tag in jQuery and set it as only content of some div?

If target div has some content, replace it and put dynamically created iframe tag.

Here is what I have tried:

```
        $(".someClass").click(function(){

             var $iframe = $('<iframe allowfullscreen  ></iframe>', {
                'width': 650,
                'height': 580,              
                'src': someUrl
             });
             $('#someId').html($iframe);

        });
```

This code actually adds iframe to the div but the iframe is missing src atribute. 
What can be wrong with this code?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you asking [the same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613904/create-iframe-in-jquery) with the same code after you already accepted an answer to your other question?

Comment: the other question was edited, and I add a comment that things now changed and I need solution with iframe. But nobody was viewing the question. Thus, I needed your attention again.

Comment: If you want to bring more attention to your question, edit it. If your question wasn't answered, why did you mark an answer as the correct answer? That's one way to immediately take attention away from your question.

Comment: If you want more views put a bounty on the question.

Comment: Exactly -- keep in mind that you can "unaccept" an answer by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: The question was about the img tag, and it was answered correctly, but   after 30 minutes my requirements has changed and I wanted the same answer just for iframe not img tag. Originally I edited the question and unnaccept the answer. Then I accepted it again and ask another this similar question, because it is unfair to user who had provided correct answer at first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
$('<iframe />', {
    name: 'myFrame',
    id:   'myFrame',
    src: 'http://www.google.com/'
}).appendTo('div');
```

[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mWAPC/) (doesn't load google because of some restrictions on jsfiddle (I guess) but you can see that there's src attribute on the iframe)

Hope it helps!

**Edit**

```
var myFrame = $('<iframe />', { name: 'myFrame', id:   'myFrame', src: 'http://www.google.com/' });
$('div').html(myFrame);
```

[ONLINE DEMO USING HTML()](http://jsfiddle.net/mWAPC/1/)

Comment: It works great! See my edit...
> By the way, I don't really get why I got a downvote...

Comment: @sonOfOmer you can do it with html, but it doesn't make sense. you're better off using .append because that's what is really happening within .html() in this case. You are appending an element, not inserting html.

Comment: Does append removes previous content in div?

Comment: No. Append adds content to the div, html replaces the content of the div. Simple! Another way to do it with append would be: `$('div').empty().appendTo(myFrame);`

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the iframe and do

```
$('iframeID').attr('src','linktomysourcelocation');
```

Now you create the element and the code above adds the source attribute.